# Can I use copy to add data into a Postgres array datatype

Tags: postgresql

Ive created some CSV files to bulk import into Postgres 9.2 with the COPY command, but I have a problem because one of the fields in the Postgres table is an array datatype.

Is it possible to import data with COPY into an array datatype, i have both integer and text arrays ?

```
CREATE TABLE artist (
    id                          integer NOT NULL,
    name                        text NOT NULL,
    realname            text,
    urls                        text[],
    namevariations      text[],
    aliases             text[],
    releases            integer[],
    profile             text,
    members             text[],
    groups                      text[],
        data_quality    text
);
```

Comment: In principle yes, but please post some data from your CSV file and any trials and errors.

Comment: I dont know what format to put the array data into ?

Comment: Which data type exactly? `varchar[]` or e.g. `integer[]`? Please edit your question and add the `create table` statement.

Comment: If you do not post more information, including some sample data, the best possible answer you will get on your question is "Yes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
id,data
1,{1,2,3}
2,{4,5,6}
```

This assumes numeric values.

If your data contains character values that in turn can contain the delimiter (a `,` in my example) you need to enclose each value in double quotes.

```
id,data
1,{foo,bar}
2,{"foo,bar", "bar,foo"}
```

The second row will put the strings 'foo,bar' and 'bar,foo' as two elements into the array

---

**Edit**

When using a comma as the delimiter, the array values must be quoted, e.g.:

```
id,data
1,"{1,2,3}"
2,"{4,5,6}"
```

When dealing with strings, you need to use single quotes inside the array:

```
id,data
1,"{foo,bar}"
2,"{'foo,bar', 'bar,foo'}"
```

Quoting is not necessary if you use a different delimiter, e.g. `|`

Comment: are you sure there should be no quuotes or other delimeters around curly braces?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "When using a comma as the delimiter, the array values must be quoted, e.g.:" You have to quote it AND escape the the internal commas. so for this to work you have to do `1, "{1\,2\,3}"`. I think you can avoid doing the internal quotes only if you specify `WITH FORMAT CSV`

Answer (score 1):

Do a test, e.g.:

```
create table test (id int, intarr int[], textarr text[]);
insert into test values
(1, array[1,2], array['a','b']);
copy test to 'c:\data\test.txt';

truncate test;
copy test from 'c:\data\test.txt';
select * from test;
```

and check the format of the file:

```
1   {1,2}   {a,b}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is using INSERT but I want to bulk load data using COPY

Comment: @PaulTaylor: what klin was trying to show you is how you can find out for yourself by running those statements and then looking at the generated file